# Use two Google Analytics tags on a website with events

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have several websites with their own Google Analytics tags, but now I need to add a second single one to each of them to use it as a "Global Analytics Account".

I've implemeted them like this

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', '[[ MY LOCAL TAG ]]', 'auto', 'LocalTracker');
    ga('LocalTracker.send', 'pageview');
    ga('create', '[[ MY GLOBALTAG ]]', 'auto', 'GlobalTracker');
    ga('GlobalTracker.send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

My websites had events tracking like :

`<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);"></a>`

but since my implementation they are not fired, obviously because I need to rename and duplicate them like :

`<a onclick="ga('LocalTracker.send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);ga('GlobalTracker.send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);"></a>`

This is quite tidious as I have many trackings, and it's not really good for the code reading.

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either wrap you ga calls in a custom function and call that on onclick:

```
function doubleTrack(category,action,label,value) {
ga('LocalTracker.send', 'event', category, action, label], value);
ga('GlobalTracker.send',  'event', category, action, label], value);
} 

<a onclick="doubleTrack(category, action, label , value);"></a>
```

Or you can use the plugin approach to double tracking:

- [My own take](http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/double-tracking-in-ga-part-1/)
- [Simo Ahava](http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/simple-tracker-duplication-universal-analytics/)
- [David Vallejo](https://www.thyngster.com/universal-analytics-plugin-dual-tracking/)

which basically all do the same - set up a plugin that sends to two different accounts via single call. They all work by duplicating the sendHitTask (following [Google's own example in the documentation on tasks](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks#overriding_a_task)) with a different Google Account ID.